# Is it actually possible to use Rollup within NX?

Tags: storybook, rollup, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a NX monorepo Storybook component library that I need to publish. It needs to be available outside of the monorepo.

I am trying to use rollup for this but I am getting the following issue

```
    [!] (plugin rpt2) Error: libs/ui-shared/component-library/src/lib/components/header-sg/header-sg.tsx:3:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../assets/icons/icons.stack.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

import SgIcons from '../../assets/icons/icons.stack.svg';
```

I'm pointing the rollup config to the storybook TS config

```
 plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    image(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './libs/ui-shared/component-library/tsconfig.json',
    }),
    postcss(),
    terser(),
    uglify(),
  ],
```

[image]

But it doesn't seem to be using it?

Is it actually possible to use Rollup within NX? Or am I going to have to pull Storybook out of the monorepo?

Thanks